# grep, awk, bash and friends? any tool to munge this data?

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk

I'm searching through input to pull out specific info about each record. The sad thing is that each record is spread out over multiple lines, e.g. (simplified excerpt)

```
01238584 (other info) more info, more info
[age=81][otherinfo][etc, etc]
```

The only thing I really care about is the identifier and the age (*01238584* and *81*, in the example). To be crystal-clear, the only regex I can reliably search for in the input to get close to these two lines is

```
\[age=[0-9]+\]
```

... and of course I want to print out that age along with the identifying record number from the line above it, e.g.

```
 01238584   81
```

With all my sysadmin shell experience and decent awk mastery, I haven't come up with a solution yet. I can of course use `grep -B1` to get each set of lines, but then what? I always use awk for these kinds of things... but associated data is always in the same line. *sigh* This is definitely beyond my current awk skills.

Thanks for reading. Got any pointers?

---

***EDIT***
I'm going with Charlie's suggestion and changing awk's record separator, which I had never done before. It's not pretty, but neither is the input. Job is done.

```
egrep -B1 '\[age=[0-9]+\]' inputfile |
awk '
  BEGIN{ RS = "--" }
  { printf "%s  %s\n", $1, gensub(/.*\[age=([0-9]+)\].*/, "\\1", 1) }'
```

Comment: oh, it's a little arcane, but it's not inelegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you show more of the input file?  For example, if the data records are separated by blank lines, you can change the record separator using the RS special variable in Awk to have it treat multiple lines as one record.  (See, eg, http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_19.html)

In any case, I'd be tempted to do something that puts all your data records onto one line or in one logical record.

If you can't do that but you know the record ID is always on the line before the age tag, then it's easy to do in Python with readlines, which reads the whole file into a list of lines, something like this

```
 with open("file.dat") as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     for ix, line in enumerate(lines):
         if # line has age field
            # get record from lines[ix-1]
```

or, of course, you can always just keep the previous line in memory in Awk

```
 BEGIN { prevline = "" }
       { # process the line
         prevline = $0
       }
```

Comment: Definitely there is a way of doing this using sed and awk, but I give a +1 to your answer because it is so much easier and human to do it in Python. Like they say: every time somebody makes a program in sed or awk, a kitty dies.

Comment: Awk is Awksome!  You could also do a two step process if you're having problems?

Comment: Good point about `RS`. I had never used that before. After 30 minutes of playing with the input, I've got the appropriate output thanks to 1 grep + 1 awk piped together. Might not be pretty, but then .. neither is the input. I'm out of practice with my python, so I can't see how to fill in the blanks there, but IN ANY CASE, thank you SOOO much for sharing your response!

Answer (score 2):

Perl can easily serve as your friend in cases like this.  You can read the
entire file into memory to apply a regular expression over multiple lines.  Setting the input record separator to `0777` causes such a "slurping" action.  The `-n` switch simply says to read the file or files provided on the command-line.  The `-e` switch's argument constitutes the code to execute.

The regular expression's `/s` modifier allows `.` to match a newline.  The `\m` modifier allows both `^` and `$` to match immediately before and after an embedded newline.  These are key to parsing a string containing more than one logical line.  The `/g` modifier, tells the regex engine to search globally for all matches.

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" while m{^(\S+).+?\[age=(\d+)\]}gms' file
```

Given an input file like this:

```
01238584 (other info) more info, more info
[age=81][otherinfo][etc, etc]
98765432 (still other info) still more info, and more info
[age=82][and more otherinfo][etc, etc, ad infinitum]
```

...the script above outputs:

```
01238584 81
98765432 82
```

We can dissect the regular expression thusly:

```
perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -e 'print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/m{^(\S+).
```

+?[age=(\d+)]}gms/)->explain()'

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:m{^(\S+).+?\[age=(\d+)\]}gms)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  m{                       'm{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  age=                     'age='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  }gms                     '}gms'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Despite loving awk and sed and python, I've *never* touched perl before, so this was fascinating! Impressed that you can do that in a relatively short 1-liner. Thanks for the explanation!